# Global function definition

Tags: c++

I'm missing something basic.

I want the function foo() to be visible in a subroutine in a different file.

a\b\c\d\one.cpp

```
#if xyz
  void foo() { ...
```

a\two.cpp

```
void foo();
#if abc 
  uint8_t top(uint8_ val) {
    foo();
```

I get not defined errors for foo() when two.cpp is linked.

a\three.cpp

```
#if jkl
  foo();
```

foo() works fine in three.cpp

There are no namespaces.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How are you linking the objects?

Comment: What are all the ifs

Comment: I'm using PlatformIO from within Atom to compile & link.

Comment: The ifs just illustrate the structure of the code.  Some are "#if OPTION_ENABLED" , some are meant to keep a file from being compiled twice "#if !defined(APRIL)  #define APRIL "

Comment: Review ODR (one definition rule).

Comment: Review the keyword 'extern'.  It can apply to C++ functions.

Comment: review [MCVE].  We probably need to see your compile commands and the exact 'undefined' error message.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm missing something basic.

For any combination of .o files to link together, the definition of foo() can only exists once.  (ODR)  But can be declared as many times as needed.

However, I would choose to have a single .hh file with the 'declaration' line:

perhaps "foo.hh" would contain

```
 extern void foo(); // this declares the foo function
```

Any .cc file which is to use 'foo' would #include the .hh file.

And one only .cc file must implement the function body, and it also should include the .hh file.

perhaps "foo.cc" might contain

```
#include "foo.hh"

void foo() {
   // implement 
}
```

Finally, link the .o's (from compiling the .cc files) with a main.o.

Comment: I still get the undefined error.  Here's what I tried:

Comment: I'm pretty sure that three.cpp is actually being compiled as C rather than CPP.

Comment: I'm 99% sure the solution involves creating a C version of foo().  That took care of the "not defined" errors but brought up some others.

Answer (score 0):

The issue boiled down to using C++ functions within a C module.  Once I realized I was working with a C module I created a C version of foo().  That, and working some similar items, fixed the problem.